# How is the WebView than Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, browser, google-plus

I programmed a web browser. I've tried out him and on google+ wanted to say my browser would be out of date and I must have safari, chrome, firefox or ie download. How can I spend my browser as Safari or Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

When sending your HTTP requests, include a [User-Agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header in the request that identifies your browser as one of the ones you want.